# Preserve license comment in TypeScript compiled output

Tags: typescript

TypeScript compiler provides an option to remove or retain comments in the compiled JavaScript output.

What I need is the ability to remove all comments but to keep one specific comment that is in the beginning of the file containing the license text.

I am using the compiler from node.js code so a solution that works from code (and is not exposed via `tsc`).

I cannot just prepend the license text to the resulting file since that would invalidate the source mapping.

Answer (score 5):

In older versions of TypeScript you could do this with `pinned comments` like below:

```
/*!
 * Test
 */
```

These comments would still be present after compiling with `--removeComments`. This feature is gone/broken in TypeScript 1.4 but works again in the latest GitHub source code. So I think it will work again in TypeScript 1.5! :)

For future reference it was fixed in master a few days ago: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2406