# How to preserve license comments in TypeScript 2.5

Tags: typescript, tsc

I create JavaScript libraries using TypeScript v2.5 (latest) and tsc, so want to add license comments to built files.
A configuration file of TypeScript can be set `removeComments` in `tsconfig.json` . It removes some comments including license comments.

I've referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280938/preserve-license-comment-in-typescript-compiled-output) and tried to use `/** xxx */` and `/*! xxx */` , but the comments are removed.
What should I do to preserve specific comments in TypeScript using `removeComments` option? Or it has been gone yet?

```
// Source
/** Hello! */
/* Hi */
class Foo { }

// Expected
/* Hello! */
class Foo { }

// Actual
class Foo { }
```

Comment: `/*! xxx */` should and does work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks! I confirmed one line comment does work, multiple lines with `*` prefix does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`/*! xxx */` does work but only one line.
If preserve multiple lines, should add dummy comments below the comments.

```
// This will be removed
/*!
 *
 *  LICENSE
 *
 */

// This will not be removed
/*!
 *
 *  LICENSE
 *
 */
/* --------------------------- */
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Also seems to work with a single blank line below the multi-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like to make an assignment of `license = "[very long boilerplate]";` ?